# Save parameter from link on page as var in javascript

Tags: javascript

I apologize for the lack of code on this one. I am totally lost on a starting point.

On a website there is a link such as the following:

`<a href="/mywebsite?accountId=00T122233ABCEFG123&otherInforHere=blablablablabla" target="_blank">This Is My Link</a>`

I am trying to get the accountId of **00T122233ABCEFG123** and use it as a variable. The link that appears above does not have an id, so there is no way to target it other than to find "accountId" on the page, as it only appears in the page once.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't understand the downvotes read the [tour]: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a selector to target the element based on the `href` attribute, and then extract the value through the URL api

```js
const link = document.querySelector('a[href*="accountId"]');
const href = new URL(link.href);
const id = href.searchParams.get('accountId');

console.log(id);
```

```html
<a href="/mywebsite?accountId=00T122233ABCEFG123&otherInforHere=blablablablabla" target="_blank">This Is My Link</a>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I'm not sure why there are so many downvotes on the question :(

Comment: @shaneJohnson, I believe it is because you did not post any of your attempts to solve the issue.

Comment: @shaneJohnson also keep in mind that the URL api is not available in IE (*see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#browser_compatibility*)

Answer (score 1):

You can select it using the [attribute contains](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp) selector :

```
a[href*=accountId]
```

Otherwise, maybe its parent has an ID? There are many ways to target an element in a page.

Comment: The parent also does not contain an ID, but the answer above is exactly what I was needing. Thank you.